# Select an option in jquery manually

Tags: jquery, selection

Basically I have this select list with multiple options in it:

```
<select name="drop1" id="Select1" size="30">
  <?php
    for($i = 0;$i<30;$i++)
    {
       echo "<option id=\"other\" value=\"" . $i . "\"></option>\n";
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

I also have an input field:

```
<input type="text" id="inputfield"></input>
```

With jquery I want to accomplish the following: Whenever the inputfield is focussed and the arrow up is pressed, I want to move 1 option up in the select list. Same thing with arrow down. I already found out what jquery events to use to know when key down and up are pressed:

```
$('#inputfield').keydown(function(e){ //When a key is pressed..
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if ((e.keyCode || e.which) == 40) // on key down
    {
       // Make selection go down here       
    }           
    if((e.keyCode || e.which) == 38) // on key up
    {
    // Make selection go up here
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the question? Also, `if ((e.keyCode || e.which) == 40)` is weird, it will normally return `true`, not `40`.

Comment: Dropdowns are already keyboard-accessible. I don't see the point in what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to change the selection when the input field is focussed, not when the selection list is focussed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest the following:

```
$('#inputfield').keydown(function(e) { //When a key is pressed..
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which),
        select = document.getElementById('Select1');
    if (code == 38) // on pressing: ↑
    {
        select.selectedIndex = select.selectedIndex + 1;
    }
    else if (code == 40) // on pressing ↓
    {
        select.selectedIndex = select.selectedIndex - 1;
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9Lrbe/).

Updated in response to comment left by the OP (below):

> the `.change()` event of the selection list doesnt respond when I use the key up and key down method.

In order to trigger the `change` event, simply use `trigger()`; also, in the following code, I've added sanity checks to try and ensure that the key-up/key-down will only happen, and therefore only trigger a `change` event, when the `select` option's selected `option` *can* actually change:

```
$('#inputfield').keydown(function(e) { //When a key is pressed..
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which),
        select = document.getElementById('Select1'),
        current = select.selectedIndex,
        last = $(select).find('option:last').index();
    if (code == 38 && current < last) // on key down
    {
        select.selectedIndex = current + 1;
        $(select).trigger('change');
    }
    else if (code == 40 && current > 0) // on key up
    {
        select.selectedIndex = current - 1;
        $(select).trigger('change');
    }
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9Lrbe/1/).

Comment: I hope this is still related to the question:
the .change() event of the selection list doesnt respond when I use the key up and key down method.

Comment: @user1534664, please check the updated answer. Hopefully it should now work as you'd like?

Comment: @Matt, thanks! I didn't catch that you'd edited until after I edited the same thing myself (albeit somewhat later than yourself, but thank you for the catch and the help =)

Comment: Hi, I tested your code. It works, but it failed with the conditions current > 0 and current < last.

Comment: You're welcome `:)` BTW, `.trigger('change');` is just a longer version of `.change();`!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#inputfield').on('keydown',function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 40) // on key down
    {
       $('select#Select1').find("option:selected").next().attr("selected", true);
    } else if(e.keyCode === 38) // on key up
    {
       $('select#Select1').find("option:selected").prev().attr("selected", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks I tested it and this works too. I still have the same problem I posted: the .change() event of the selection list doesnt respond when I use the key up and key down method.